# How do I create a Digital Envelopes carry digitally signed data?

Tags: security, networking

As i want to send the bulk of data one at a time.
I have tried RSA based signature but it is not the way that i wanted.
Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple digital envelopes ensure the privacy of data but do not unsure the authenticity, nonrepudiation
or the integrity of the data. This can be easily achieved by digitally signing the data
before wrapping it with a digital envelope.

[image: You can add hash function]